# Javascript dynamic insert form row by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i have this problem:
I've created into my form a part of it where users can choose to insert from 0 to 10 row.
Each row contains 3 input.

Html code is:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputCity">Mesi a carico</label>
      <select name="mesi_carico[]" id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputState">Min 3 anni?</label>
      <select name="min_3_anni[]" id="inputState" class="form-control">
      <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Si">Si</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputZip">% Detr. Spettante</label>
      <select name="perc_carico[]" id="inputState" class="form-control">
      <option value="100">100%</option>
        <option value="50">50%</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here my JSCode

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 10;
    var wrapper = $(".container1");
    var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputCity">Mesi a carico</label>
      <select name="mesi_carico[]" id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputState">Min 3 anni?</label>
      <select name="min_3_anni[]" id="inputState" class="form-control">
      <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Si">Si</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputZip">% Detr. Spettante</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
      <option value="100">100%</option>
        <option value="50">50%</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
        } else {
            alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Where is the issue?
And, I need to transfer the value array like array[0] array[1] array [2] ecc ecc... I'm not sure to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Dinamico CMS?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant Dinamic (and he insert Dinamico)

Comment: `Dinamic` isn't a word, you meant `dynamic`

Comment: Yes.............................